# Have Camera fill up parent box in Portrait mode

Tags: android, python, kivy, kivy-language

So currently I have the kivy code as this:
:
    orientation: "vertical"
    display: entry
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    id: entry
    multiline: False
    Camera:
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: True
```

But I would like the camera to fill up the parent div and be in portrait mode. How would I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to allow the video/image to stretch.

```
Camera:
    allow_stretch: True
```

To rotate the widget, you could also simply use a Rotate instruction:

```
Camera:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix:
        Rotate:
            angle: 90
            origin: self.center

    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix:
```

But then it's not correctly constrained by the parent (you need a way to invert width/heignt constraints).

Something like:

```
Widget:
    id: proxy
    Camera:
        center: self.size and proxy.center
        size: proxy.height, proxy.width

        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix:
            Rotate:
                angle: 90
                origin: self.center

        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix:
```

Should do the trick.

(can't test right now, on phone)